# npm install sqlite3 error on BeagleBone Black

Tags: node.js, sqlite, npm, installation, beagleboneblack

I can not seem to install SQLite3 for NODE.JS on my BeagleBone Black.
No matter what I do I end up with a variety of errors depending on what I try.
I have read and tried a couple of threads on stack overflow to no avail.

The last try I did was after running

```
  sudo npm install -g node-gyp, sudo apt-get install build-essential
  sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make
```

and then finally I ran

```
 sudo npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source
```

But to no avail and en entire day wasted I get the following ->

```
npm ERR! node v4.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! sqlite3@3.1.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@3.1.0 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --   fallback-to-build'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the sqlite3 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls sqlite3
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/debian/winShare/npm-debug.log
```

This is when I simply go
    sudo npm install sqlite3

Error:

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.8.13-bone47
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/debian/winShare/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v46-linux-arm/node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=/home/debian/winShare/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v46-linux-arm"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/debian/winShare/node_modules/sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v4.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/debian/winShare/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v46-linux-arm/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/home/debian/winShare/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v46-linux-arm' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/debian/winShare/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:817:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 3.8.13-bone47
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node"  "/home/debian/winShare/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/debian/winShare/node_modules/sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v4.0.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.10
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/debian/winShare/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v46-linux-arm/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/home/debian/winShare/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v46-linux-arm' (1)
npm ERR! Linux 3.8.13-bone47
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "sqlite3"
npm ERR! node v4.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! sqlite3@3.1.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@3.1.0 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the sqlite3 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls sqlite3
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/debian/winShare/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to root `sudo su`
the run

```
apt-get update
apt-get install sqlite3
```